# XSLT/XML Data Transform: Date to DateTime?

Tags: datetime, xslt, xslt-1.0

Im doing an XML data transform using XSLT and I'm trying to convert a value from a date(string) to a DateTime value. So for instance the value being passed in  is a date value and I want to cast it as DateTime in my XSLT but I have been unsuccessful. I am using xml version="1.0 also. Does anyone have any ideas on how to convert the  xslt value to DateTime?

Comment: XSLT 1.0 doesn't have a "DateTime" type. Are you just trying to change the format of the datetime? It would help if you showed a sample of your input. and the output you expect in this case. Thanks!

Comment: In XSLT 2.0, use the function `fn:dateTime($date, xs:time('00:00:00'))`.

Comment: Im using XSLT 1.0! :( thank you though I know that would be perfect otherwise @MichaelKay

Comment: Time to move forward. 2.0 has been around for over 10 years!